# how to transpose values two by two using shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have my data in a file store by lines like this :

```
3.172704445659,50.011996744997,3.1821975358417,50.012335988197,3.2174797791605,50.023182479597
```

And I would like 2 columns :

```
3.172704445659 50.011996744997
3.1821975358417 50.012335988197
3.2174797791605 50.023182479597
```

I know sed command for delete ','(sed "s/,/ /") but I don't know how to "back to line" every two digits ?

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One in awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s%s",$i,(i%2&&i!=NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
```

Output:

```
3.172704445659 50.011996744997
3.1821975358417 50.012335988197
3.2174797791605 50.023182479597
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution viable for those without knowledge of `awk` command - simple `for` loop over an array of numbers.

```
IFS=',' read -ra NUMBERS < file

NUMBERS_ON_LINE=2
INDEX=0
for NUMBER in "${NUMBERS[@]}"; do
  if (($INDEX==$NUMBERS_ON_LINE-1)); then
    INDEX=0
    echo "$NUMBER"
  else
    ((INDEX++))
    echo -n "$NUMBER "
  fi
done
```

Comment: `printf` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already tried `sed`, here is a solution using sed:

```
sed -r "s/(([^,]*,){2})/\1\n/g; s/,\n/\n/g" YOURFILE
```

- `-r` uses sed extended regexp
- there are **two** substitutions used:

  1. the first substitution, with the `(([^,]*,){2})` part, captures two comma separated numbers at once and store them into `\1` for reuse: `\1` holds in your example at the first match: `3.172704445659,50.011996744997,`. Notice: both commas are present.

     - `(([^,]*,){2})` means capture a sequence consisting of NOT comma - that is the `[^,]*` part followed by a `,`
     - we want two such sequences - that is the `(...){2}` part
     - and we want to capture it for reuse in `\1` - that is the outer pair of parentheses
     - then substitute with `\1\n` - that just inserts the newline after the match, in other words a newline after each second comma
  2. as we have now a comma before the newline that we need to get rid of, we do a second substitution to achieve that:

     - `s/,\n/\n/g`
     - a comma followed by newline is replace with only newline - in other words the comma is deleted

Answer (score 0):

`awk` and `sed` are powerful tools, and in fact constitute  programming languages in their own right. So, they can, of course, handle this task with ease.

But so can `bash`, which will have the benefits of being more portable (no outside dependencies), and executing faster (as it uses only built-in functions):

```
IFS=$', \n'
values=($(</path/to/file))
printf '%.13f %.13f\n' "${values[@]}"
```