# How to transpose values and output results in new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My data :

```
"1,2,3,4,5,64,3,9",,,,,1,aine
"2,3,4,5",,,,,3,bb
"3,4,5,6,6,2",,,,,2,ff
```

I have to transpose values inside "...." delimiter like this : [how to transpose values two by two using shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642686/how-to-transpose-values-two-by-two-using-shell/65643709#65643709)

and Output the result (2 columns) in a new file with the filename = (last-1) columns digits. I have to transpose for each lines of my input file.

What I would like :

$ ls

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

example : cat 1

```
 1 2
 3 4
 5 64 
 3 9
```

cat 2 :

```
3 4
5 6
6 2
```

cat 3 :

```
2 3
4 5
```

Bonus : If I can get every last words (last columns) as title of new files It would be perfect.

Comment: Your prose description is insufficient.  Please provide sample output to clarify.

Comment: what is the expected output if 2 input lines have the same number (eg, `1`) in the next-to-last column?

Comment: my input file doesn't have same number in next-to-last column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took a time but i finally solved your problem with the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r LINE; do
    FILE_NAME=$(echo {$LINE##*,,,,,} | cut -d ',' -f 1 | tr -d "\"")
    DATA=$(echo ${LINE%%,,,,,*} | tr -d "\"" | tr "," " ")
    touch $FILE_NAME
    i=1
    for num in $DATA ;do
        echo -n "$num"
        if [[ $(($i%2)) == 0 ]]; then
            echo ""
        else
            echo -n " "
        fi
        i=$((i+1))
    done > $FILE_NAME
done < input.txt
```

in my solution i imagine that your input should be placed in file `input.txt` and all of your input lines have `,,,,,` as a separator. Works like a charm with your sample input.

Comment: Thank you, How do I modify your code if I have float number : "1.1,2,3,4,5.6,6.76787"

Comment: I think it's going to work with float numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no colons in the input (choose a different temporary delimiter if necessary) the first part can be done with:

```
awk '{s = ""; n = split($2,k,","); for(i = 1; i <= n; i+=2 ) { s = sprintf( "%s%c%s:%s", s, s ? ":" : "", k[i+1], k[i])} $2 = s}1' FS=\" OFS=\" input  | sort -t , -k6n | tr : ,
```

eg:

```
$ cat input
"1,2,3,4,5,64,3,9",,,,,1,aine
"2,3,4,5",,,,,3,bb
"3,4,5,6,6,2",,,,,2,ff
$ awk '{s = ""; n = split($2,k,","); for(i = 1; i <= n; i+=2 ) { s = sprintf( "%s%c%s:%s", s, s ? ":" : "", k[i+1], k[i])} $2 = s}1' FS=\" OFS=\" input  | sort -t , -k6n | tr : ,
"2,1,4,3,64,5,9,3",,,,,1,aine
"4,3,6,5,2,6",,,,,2,ff
"3,2,5,4",,,,,3,bb
```

But it's not clear why you want to do the first part at all when you can just skip straight to part 2 with:

```
awk '{n = split($2,k,","); m = split($3, j, ","); fname = j[6]; 
    for( i = 1; i <= n; i+=2 ) printf("%d %d\n", k[i+1], k[i]) > fname}' FS=\" input
```

My answer can't keep up with the changes to the question!  If you are outputting the lines into files, then there is no need to sort on the penultimate column.  If you want the filenames to be the final column, it's not clear why you ever mentioned using the penultimate column at all.  Just change `fname` in the above to `j[7]` to get the final column.

Comment: yes off course, you are right, we can skip the first part